# Could not find gem 'byebug x64-mingw32' for run server ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I when run server i get above error i try to install 'gem install web-console,byebug,tzinfo-data' i get this error :

```
C:\Users\RaminFP>gem install web-console
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
C:\RubyDevKit\bin\rm.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
C:\RubyDevKit\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
C:\RubyDevKit\bin\echo.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
ERROR:  Error installing web-console:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160212-7132-1g0f7us.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
  0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x290000, State 0x10000
 C:\RubyDevKit\bin\rm.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
 makefile:187: recipe for target 'clean-static' failed
 make: [clean-static] Error 1 (ignored)
  0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x290000, State 0x10000
 C:\RubyDevKit\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
 makefile:170: recipe for target 'clean' failed
 make: [clean] Error 1 (ignored)

 make "DESTDIR="
  0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
 AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x290000, State 0x10000
  C:\RubyDevKit\bin\echo.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
 makefile:260: recipe for target 'debug_inspector-x64-mingw32.def' failed
 make: *** [debug_inspector-x64-mingw32.def] Error 1

 make failed, exit code 2

 Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
 Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-     mingw32/2.2.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
```

i use IDE intellij for runserver and get error , not find,

what happen here?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you need to rebase dlls in your bin directory by doing:-

`rebase.exe -b 0x50000000 msys-1.0.dll`

reference: http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1403